# External use of Wordpress JSON API

Tags: php, json, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I've been going through the Wordpress JSON API documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/ to solve this issue, but I haven't made much headway there or with google.

I'm doing fine in my external code with simple GET requests, but the moment I try to do anything that would require authentication I'm coming up short. For example, I can pull all the information from a public page "http://localhost/WPPodcast/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/13", but I can't pull anything from a private page or a password-restricted page. If I'm having trouble with a GET request using an external program, then I'm definitely going to have issues doing a POST/DELETE/UPDATE.

Below is my code

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/WPPodcast/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/11',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,

    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        // I don't see anything about authentication tokens
                xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + Base64.encode( 'username:password' ) );

        console.log("beforeSend")
    },
    success: function( data, txtStatus, xhr ) {
        console.log( data );
        console.log( xhr.status );
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    // process data
    console.log("done")
    console.log("data: " + data)

    

}).fail(function() {
    // to be continued
    console.log("fail")
}).always(function() {
    // to be continued
    console.log("always")
});
```

Is there a way to use WP REST API from an external application to access data that requires authentication?
If so, can you please tell me what I've done wrong, point me towards a tutorial, etc.?

Comment: If you want to use Basic Auth, you probably want to have [this plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth) installed unless you want to roll your own. However, WP 5.6 added support for [Application Passwords](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/) and I would encourage you to check that out.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I'll look into it.

Comment: Also worth checking out: [REST API - Authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/).